# Pointer not being set correctly in function

Tags: c

I have a code where I use a pointer

One of the functions is in file 1

In the main file I call the function of file 1

When I pass the pointer it is not being defined,

I get Test is NULL message

What is the correct way for me to use this?

my code:

**File 1**

```
struct mystruct {
    unsigned short id;
    int number;
    ....
}

struct mystruct *test_check(state *ck, char *name);

void GetMytest(state *ck, char *name, struct mystruct *test) {
        checkfield(ck, name);
        test = test_check(ck, name);
        .....
}
```

**Main file**

```
struct mystruct *test

void MainTest() {

    state *ck = check_new();
    .....

    GetMytest(ck, "Stats", test);
    
    if(test == NULL)
        printf("Test is NULL");

}
```

Comment: We need at least the `test_check` definition. Declarations (and even better definitions) of the other functions and types would be helpful too

Comment: This is C, therefore, `GetMytest(ck, "Stats", test);` cannot possibly modify the value held by the pointer `test`, as the local by-value argument shadows the global `test` (which is NULL on inception as a global and passed from `main`). `test = ...` means *nothing* to the caller of `GetMytest` (i.e. `main`).

Comment: This a classic error. Changing `test` inside `GetMytest` will **not** change `test` in `main`. C uses pass by value, **not** pass by reference. So either pass a pointer to `test` or let the function return the new value and assign it to `test`. Since `test` is global you could in principle remove it as function argument. Then it would work but global variables should be avoided.

Comment: Here is a few links explaining it (a little search will give you many. many more): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72311632/what-does-pass-by-value-mean-exactly-in-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149959/why-would-i-pass-function-parameters-by-value-in-c

Comment: Please provide a [mre], skipping includes and headers and the `...........` leave to much to guessing.

Comment: @yunnosch I don't see the need to post more of the code, the problem was obvious just by looking at the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `test = test_check(ck, name);` in `GetMytest` only modifies the local argument variable `test`, not the global variable by the same name.

If you want to update the pointer in the calling scope (the `MainTest` function or the global scope), you must pass a pointer to this variable.

I do something similar in some of my code

Try as follows

**File 1:**

```
void GetMytest(state *ck, char *name, struct mystruct **test) {
        checkfield(ck, name);
        *test = test_check(ck, name);
        .....
}
```

**Main function:**

```
void MainTest() {

    state *ck = check_new();
    .....

    GetMytest(ck, "Stats", &test);
    
    if (test == NULL)
        printf("Test is NULL");
}
```

If the other functions are correct this should solve the problem.