# why do I need to add an & sign while allocating a memory space inside a functions?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pointer-to-pointer

I wanted to try making an allocate function for a cell in a list, but when using it inside another functions, I need to add an "&" sign

I am aware of what "&" means in c (the address of the variable)but I don't understand why do I need to use it here?

this the allocate function I made

```
/*1*/void Allocate(struct cell **p) {
  (*p) = malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
}
```

that's the function i used it in

```
void Makelist(struct cell **headP, int n){
    struct cell *q;
    struct cell *p;
    int value;
    Allocate(&p);///whyyyy????
    *headP=p;
    Ass_adr(p,NULL);
    printf("\ngive the value on cell 1:");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    Ass_val(p,value);
        for (int i=1; i<n;i++){
            Allocate(&q);
            Ass_adr(q,NULL);
            Ass_adr(p,q);
            printf("give the value in the cell %d:",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&value);
            Ass_val(p,value);
            p=q;
        }
}
```

I expected to only type

```
Allocate(p);
```

yet if I don't add the "&" inside the main program it functions normally

Comment: You need the `&` here because you need to pass the address of  `p`.  Perhaps the question you need to ask is "Why is the argument of Allocate of type `struct cell **`?"

Comment: @nada, Ask yourself why a `&` in `scanf("%d",&value);`?  You code needs `Allocate(&p);` for a similar reason.

Comment: Related: [What does pass-by value mean exactly in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311792/2472827)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the passed pointer you have a direct access to the original object and can change it.

There is written in the C Standard (6.2.5 Types, p.#20):

> — **A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object
> type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object
> whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced
> type**. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes
> called "pointer to T".

So to change an original object (that in turn can be a pointer) in a function you need to pass a reference to it that is a pointer.

In this code snippet

```
struct cell *p;
//...
Allocate(&p);
```

the pointer `p` is passed to the funtion Allocate by reference. So the function changes the original passed object (pointer) `p`

```
(*p) = malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
```

Otherwise if to pass the pointer directly then it will be passed to the function by value. That is the function will deal with a copy of the original pointer and the copy will be changed. The original pointer will stay unchanged.

Consider the following simple deminstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *p )
{
    p = NULL;
}

void g( int **p )
{
    *p = NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;

    int *p = &x;

    printf( "Before calling function f() p = % p\n", ( void * )p );

    f( p );

    printf( "After  calling function f() p = % p\n", ( void * )p );

    printf( "Before calling function g() p = % p\n", ( void * )p );

    g( &p );

    printf( "After  calling function g() p = % p\n", ( void * )p );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Before calling function f() p = 00CFF9FC
After  calling function f() p = 00CFF9FC
Before calling function g() p = 00CFF9FC
After  calling function g() p = 00000000
```

Comment: "In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it."--> not really.  Aside from maybe `foo(int a[1])` like code, C simply does not have _ pass by reference_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Elements of the array are passed by reference through the pointer to the first element of the array. Actually the above declaration is equivalent to foo( int * ). Moreover the function does not even know that the argument expression was an array.

Comment: Similar, yet code analysis tools, and users, see the `1` in `foo(int a[1])` as a implication of the number of elements needed.  `foo(int *a)` does not provide that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It does not matter. With the same success you may call the function like int x; foo( &x );

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, really. C passes by value. So if a programmer wants to pass by reference, they take a pointer and give it to C to pass by value. So the called function receives the value of a pointer, and that value is a reference to the programmer’s desired target. That is the historical use of “pass by reference.” C++’s adoption of a different meaning for “reference” has no bearing on this.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Although it may not matter with a simple compilation, static analyzers can use the `[1]` [... to indicate the expected bounds of the array.](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/API05-C.+Use+conformant+array+parameters).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica We are not discussing static analysers. We are discussing what means passing by reference in C and how to change in a function an original object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow   C does not define _pass by reference_ and so we are left with purported historical meaning, what _pass by reference_ means today in general and what it means in other current languages.  Using _pass by reference_, as if it had a clear universal meaning in C does not get the core of OP's blight as well as simply asserting C lacks _pass by reference_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The term "pass by reference" is a general term. In different languages there are used different mechanism to implement the concept. For example in the C Standard there is written: "A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type. A
pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced
type."

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Fair point about "... object whose value provides a reference to an entity ...".  Sounds like we agree C does not define _pass by reference_ and so we are relying on others to define what it _precisely_ means.  Trying to fit _pass by reference_  in `foo(int *)` and at the same time allowing it to be called _pass by value_ of a pointer is less clear the simple calling it _pass by value_ of a pointer and C lacks _pass by reference_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If a pointer provides a reference to an object pointed to by the pointer then pass by reference means passing  the reference (pointer) to the object. Do not mix this notion with other language implementations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256989/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am sorry. I never take part in chats.

Answer (score 2):

> `Allocate(&p);///whyyyy????`

The short answer is: Because you want the function to change the value of `p`

Further explanation:

In C all function calls uses "pass-by-value" for the function arguments. So if you have:

```
int x = 42;
some_function(x);
```

The function `some_function` will receive the value 42 - just as if your call was `some_function(42);`. The function knows nothing about the variable `x`.

A more detailed example:

```
void foo(int x) {
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 42
    x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 5
}

void bar(void) {
    int x = 42;
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 42
    foo(x);
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will still print 42
}
```

Even if `foo` do change `x` it does **not** change `x` inside `bar`. The `x` in the two functions are different variables. There is no relation between them. The function `foo` just received the value `42` and used it to initialize its local variable `x` but that has nothing to do with `x` inside `bar`.

So what do we do in C when we want `foo` to change the value of `x` inside `bar`?

Answer: We pass a **pointer to x** instead of `x`

That looks like:

```
void foo(int* x) {       // Notice all the * in the function.
    printf("%d\n", *x);  // Will print 42
    *x = 5;              // Will change the value of x inside bar
    printf("%d\n", *x);  // Will print 5
}

void bar(void) {
    int x = 42;
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 42
    foo(&x);            // Notice the &
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will now print 5 as x was changed by foo
}
```

Now `foo` receives a pointer to `x` inside `bar`. That's the purpose of `&x`. Using that pointer `foo` can access `x` in `bar` using a dereference of the pointer, i,.e. the `*x` part.

In your code the principle is just the same. You want `Allocate` to change the value of `p`. Consequently, you have to pass `&p`.